# Unable to set template for default handle in local.xml

Tags: layout, local.xml

I am trying to set template for root block in default handle in local.xml file.But when I reload the page , nothing appears.After changing default to checkout_cart_index or any other request specific handle, page is rendered.how do i change template in default handle.

Here is my local.xml

`<layout>
    <default>
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/2columns-right.phtml"   />
    </default>
</layout>`

Answer (score 1):

Balaji.

you need just set reference name and don't require to define  block type again.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
    <reference name="root">
         <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </default>
</layout>
```

See at My [blog](http://www.amitbera.com/how-to-change-page-layout-in-magento/)

Answer (score 1):

Amit forgot to close the reference handle

This should work:

```
<default>
   <reference name="root">
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
   </reference>
</default>
```